# EXDATE field in Android CalendarContract.Events is always null

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar, recurring-events

I have a Google calendar with recurring events. When I download the ical I can see that it has EXDATE for recurring event exceptions, but when querying the field with Android (KitKat) I always get rrule but no exdate or exrule.
The Instances table is correct, but I was hoping that there would be a way to detect that an event has been deleted rather than parsing the recurrence rules and matching the results with the instances seen.

If anyone can let me know if you have ever seen a non-null exdate field in the Android calendar.

All the questions I've seen have been about inserting new exceptions.